# `ngIf` issue, how to?

Tags: javascript, angular

For some reason, `ngIf` doesn't seem to work.

If i add `*ngIf="main.visible"` the code fails, if I remove it the code works just fine.

Any ideas

Here is my example:  http://codepen.io/patrioticcow/pen/YqxVNq?editors=1010

UPDATE: Ill accept the answer that `ngIf` is not resolved at that place in the code. If you read this, and you think this is a bug (that might be resolved) please point that out in a comment or something. Thanks

```js
// add component 
(function(app) {
  app.AppComponent = ng.core
    .Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: `<div *ngFor="#main of content; #i=index"  *ngIf="main.visible">{{main.title}} - {{main.visible}} </div>`
    })
    .Class({
      constructor: function() {

        this.content = [{
          title: 'test a',
          visible: true
        }, {
          title: 'test b',
          visible: true
        }, {
          title: 'test c',
          visible: true
        }, {
          title: 'test d',
          visible: false
        }, ];
      }
    });
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));

// bootstrap app
(function(app) {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    ng.platform.browser.bootstrap(app.AppComponent);
  });
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

```css
html {
  background: linear-gradient(#0143A3, #0273D4);
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 180px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/Rx.umd.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2-all.umd.dev.js"></script>
<my-app>

</my-app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the local variable main isn't resolved at that point. create an extra div and have the *ngIf inside the *ngFor

Comment: damnit, that breaks my UI

Comment: it works for me, i just modified your codepen to this

template: `
     <div *ngFor="#main of content; #i=index">
      <div *ngIf="main.visible">
       {{main.title}} - {{main.visible}}
      </div>
     </div>`

Comment: I believe you, I was saying that my UI is more complex then the actual example

Comment: gotcha! maybe, share your actual code, the part that you use the *ngIf or the error logs you get

Comment: Based on your answer, my question would be, is this a angular bug? Because in Angular 1 this worked.

Answer (score 1):

## Updated to angular2 beta 8 and above

Now as from angular2 beta 8 we can use `*ngIf and`*ngFor` on same component [see here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6304)
Alternatively we can use -

## ngFor using template:-

```
<template ngFor #abc [ngForOf]="someArray">
    code here....
</template>
```

## ngIf using template:-

```
<template [ngIf]="show">
        code here....
    </template>
```

Comment: nice, ill give that a try, thanks

Comment: yups y, your welcome

Answer (score 0):

`*ngFor` and `*ngIf` on the same element is not supported

```ts
<div *ngFor="let main of content; let i=index"  *ngIf="main.visible">
        {{main.title}} - {{main.visible}}
</div>
```

instead the full syntax needs to be used for at least one of both like

```ts
<template ngFor let-main [ngForOf]="content" let-i="index">
  <div *ngIf="main.visible">
        {{main.title}} - {{main.visible}}
  </div>
</template>
```

or

```ts
<template [ngIf]="condition">
  <div *ngFor="let main of content; #i=index">
        {{main.title}} - {{main.visible}}
  </div>
</template>
```

depending on what the desired behavior is.

See also [**CodePen example**](http://codepen.io/zoechi/pen/JXpYvj?editors=1010#anon-login)